# spatial autocorrelation, some features with no nearby neighbors

Tags: r, regression, autocorrelation, spatial, ecology

I have a set of point features that span the African continent. Some are clustered and show positive autocorrelation in a various measured ecological characteristics at scales of less than ~150km. Others are up to 900km from the nearest neighbor and are (predictably) not autocorrelated with their nearest neighbors.

I would like to follow Dormman et al. 2007 Methods to account for spatial autocorrelation in the analysis of species distributional data: a review *Ecography* to analyze my data using spatial regression. 
However, I can't build spatial weights matrices without assigning at lesat one neighbor to all features, including the far-flung, isolated features. What is the best practice here?

I can see a few options:

1) Use a large distance threshold to make sure all points have a neighbor because that is required by the R spdep function nb2listw which calculates the spatial weights (and by any spatial regression technique I'm aware of); this method used by Brierly et al. 2016 Quantifying Global Drivers of Zoonotic Bat Viruses: A Process-Based Perspective *American Naturalist*

OR

2) Justify *not* using spatial regression *because* the underlying biology suggests that only close neighbors are truly related.

OR

Perhaps there's another option I am unaware of.

Comment: A standard approach is Kriging: have you considered that?

Comment: Interesting. I had not considered that. I tend to think of kriging for interpolation across continuous surfaces, not for individual point features. But I *think* I understand how this *could* work. 
Is this equivalent to using a weights matrix with the smaller ecologically meaningful distance threshold and setting the zero.position argument = TRUE in spded functions moran.test and lagsarlm? i.e., Kriging beyond an area of neighbor influence will have no effect on the isolated features?

Comment: Whether kriging could be applied to point features depends partly on what they represent: are they a sample or are they the entirety of a population?  For theory and examples of how kriging can be applied to spatial point processes, see Diggle & Ribeiro Jr., *Model-Based Geostatistics.*

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Mine are a sample of a population of many points.